# Can't alter/change access rights

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, filesystem

I've downloaded some gopro footage to my local hd and then copied the files from my hd to an external drive. Whenever I want to change the access rights it will switch back to read only in Nautilus. Likewise if I change the ones for the files below. How can I give full rights? I need to process the footage on a mac.

[image]

sudo parted -l /dev/sdb

```
Modell: JMicron Generic (scsi)
Festplatte  /dev/sdb:  500GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/512B
Partitionstabelle: msdos

Nummer  Anfang  Ende   Größe  Typ      Dateisystem  Flags
 1      1049kB  500GB  500GB  primary  ext2
```

Comment: Is the external drive mounted as read-only? Try to change the permission from the command line as the root user and check what happens.

Comment: My user (nuc) can change and delete files, but only on this nuc. How?

Comment: Does `mount` say anything useful?

Comment: @heemayl : I've postet above what it says.

Comment: Looks like it is mounted as FUSE FS. Check the solutions given [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/74806/216503)

Comment: Must be this: /dev/sdb1 on /media/nuc/500GB type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096). I can't relate this answers to my problem.

Comment: Please do a `sudo fdisk -l` and add the output.

Comment: I've added the output above.

Comment: `fdisk -l` does not support **GPT**, try `sudo parted -l /dev/sdb` and add the output. I am almost certain that you have a Windows partition as shown by the type **fuseblk**, i just want to be absolutely sure of that.

Comment: @heemayl I added it. Please mind that I formated the drive with Gparted as EXT2 in between. It says I'm not the owner in Nautilus.

Answer (score 2):

From this line
/dev/sdb1 on /media/nuc/500GB type fuseblk
(rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
I see that external drive filesystem is NTFS and it was by default mounted without respect to NTFS permissions. In this case all files/directories will have the same permissions and attempts to change them will be ignored.

I have solved similar problem by making permanent share with explicit settings:
write line
UUID=C848-2413 /mnt/E_DRIVE vfat rw,user,exec,umask=002
into /etc/fstab where UUID is from `sudo blkid`. (Then mkdir /mnt/E_DRIVE, setting permissions, then umount / mount.)

Simpler alternative is to install special tool:
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/ntfs-config/

Comment: The special tool somehow doesn't allow me to delete files via delete button. Is this normal? I could reformat it, if you can tell me a file format that both ubuntu and mac osx understands.

Comment: You can reformat external HDD as FAT/FAT32/ext2f file system then copy again from linux HDD to it (I assume you have a copy of the files, please check before formatting.) From what I see in http://guides.macrumors.com/Drives_and_Filesystems they all are supported by macos x.

Comment: I formated to ext2. But unfortunately I don't own the drive anymore (from what I see in nautilus). I deinstalled the suggested special tool, but it didn't change anything.