# Can't write to partion after creating it with GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a 1000 gig  Windows SATA HD.

I don't want to delete the Windows installation for case I will sell this hard drive with the PC it came with.

Using Gparted, on by Ubuntu 17.10 PC running from a SSD drive, I shrinked the 1000 SATA hard drive so the Windows in left untouched,

Created a 400 Gig partion EXT4

And I can't create Folder within this partition but can see it from the FileManager.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change permissions on external drives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74806/how-can-i-change-permissions-on-external-drives)

Comment: Tks will look at the link you provided

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a GUI tool ? I tried most of the commands at the link you proved and can't still create a folder within that partition,....

Comment: Usually I do this from terminal by `sudo chown $USER:$USER -R /media/$USER/mountpoint`. I do not know GUI solutions.

Comment: From file manager I see  /media/jedi/BackUP

Comment: jedi@jedi-computer:~$ sudo chown $USER:$jedi -R /media/$jedi/BackUP
[sudo] password for jedi: 
chown: cannot access '/media//BackUP': No such file or directory
jedi@jedi-computer:~$ sudo chown $USER:$^Cdi -R /media/$jedi/BackUP
jedi@jedi-computer:~$ sudo chown $jedi:$jedi -R /media/$jedi/BackUP
chown: cannot access '/media//BackUP': No such file or directory
jedi@jedi-computer:~$

Comment: Full command in you case is as follows: `sudo chown $USER:$USER -R /media/$USER/BackUP`. `$USER` is variable, do not touch it. It would convert to your username by the shell. $jedi variable is empty, as it is not defined.

Comment: LOL  worked....  That is Why GUI was easier for me, I messed up your command but now it's ok  !!! TKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand, your mount point is named `BackUP`.

So you should take ownership of the filesystem with:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER -R /media/$USER/BackUP
```

Comment: I don,t know how to ACCEPT answer in the FORUM and Mark my questions as Solved.. DO I edit the subject ( Question ) and put SOLVED in front as we do in some forum ?

Comment: You do not need to add "solved". See this [help topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers).